# How do I keep DateTime in DateTime format after converting by SimpleDateFormat in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, datetime

I am new to scala so this question may sound obvious.
I need to extract the date only from DateTime in 2015-04-09 format. But I get the time too as in 2015-04-09T12:58:17.123+05:30

So, I converted the DateTime as -

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime
import java.text._

val yesterday = DateTime.yesterday
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val date      = formatter.format(yesterday)
```

After the conversion, the type of date is **String**. But I want the type of date in **DateTime with only the date** given.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `SimpleDateFormat` with joda-time (I guess it works at all due to some implicit conversion from `DateTime` to `java.util.Date`). Use `DateTimeFormat` instead in order to format dates as string.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a question about joda time as nscala is just a wrapper on top of it. You can either do .withTime and settime to 0.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTime(int, int, int, int)

But I would the way you would want is to only keep the date aspect which is by doing `.toLocalDate` on DateTime object.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalDate()

Comment: possibly http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay() instead of `withTime`